# Python matrix inner product

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, inner-product

I am trying to solve the below question:

```
'''
        Take in two matrices as numpy arrays, X and Y. Determine whether they have an inner product.
        If they do not, return False. If they do, return the resultant matrix as a numpy array.
        '''
```

with the following code:

```
def mat_inner_product(X,Y):

    if X.shape != Y.shape:
        return False
    else:
        return np.inner(X,Y)
```

I got the following error message:

```
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_mat_inner_product (test_methods.TestPython1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/test_methods.py", line 27, in test_mat_inner_product
    self.assertTrue(np.array_equal(result2, correct2))
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

What does it mean "False is not true"? Do I have a logic error? Or should I use .dot() rather than .inner()? What is the difference?

Comment: It means that your function returned `False`, but that that is not correct, that your function should have returned `True`.

Comment: Show us the test code as well

Comment: @hpaulj the test case is behind the scene that I have no access to

Comment: It's running some test on your function, and it fails.  It's testing your `result` against a `correct` one.  It's not telling us what's being tested or what it expects.  Have you run your own tests?  Show us some tests of your own.  Do they look right.  In particular is your `shape` test right?

Answer (score 4):

One can calculate the *inner product* given that **the last dimension of both matrices are the same**. So you should not check whether `X.shape` is equal to `Y.shape`, but only the last dimension:

```
def mat_inner_product(X,Y):
    if X.shape[-1] != Y.shape[-1]:
        return False
    else:
        return np.inner(X,Y)
```

Furthermore the number of dimensions - the `.ndim` (which is the `len(X.shape)` - do not have to be the same either: you can calculate the inner product of a 2d matrix with a 3d tensor.

You can however omit the check and use a `try`-`except` item:

```
def mat_inner_product(X,Y):
    try:
        return np.inner(X,Y)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Now we only have to rely on the fact that `numpy` has implemented the logic of the inner matrix correctly, and will raise a `ValueError` in case the inner product cannot be calculated.

> Or should I use `.dot()` rather than `.inner()`? What is the difference?

The difference with the dot product is that it works with the **second last** dimension of `Y` (instead of the last that is used in `np.inner()`). So in case you would work with `numpy.dot(..)` the check would be:

```
def mat_dot_product(X,Y):
    if X.shape[-1] != Y.shape[-2]:
        return False
    else:
        return np.dot(X,Y)
```

But again, you can make use of a `try`-`except` structure here.

Comment: By "number of dimensions" are you talking about the rank?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: after rereading your comment. I meant the `len(..)` of the `X.shape`, etc.

Comment: I think what threw me off is the idea of a "3D matrix". You can have a rank-3 tensor, or you can have a 3D array, but 3D matrix mixes terminology a little bit. A matrix is always 2D by definition.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: yeah the correct name is indeed tensor. I modified it. Better?